# How to allow themes to call my extension blocks through widgets

Tags: blocks, filter, widgets

I have an extension that is structured like this:

```
Myextension
└── Mymodule
    └── etc
    │   └── config.xml
    └── Helper
        └── Data.php
```

The data extends `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` and has this method which returns some HTML:

```
public function sayHi()
{
    return 'Hello world!';
}
```

**My question**

Is it possible to provide a way so that `sayHi` can be called from what ever theme or template (like product page) using the widget in the admin?

Should I create a block/filter/widget?

Does Magento have some hook system?

I read lot of documentation/tutorial/book but I couldn't grasp the Magento workflow for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-widget-development-in-magento--cms-23015) that shows you how to create widgets
You will need a block that implements the interface `Mage_Widget_Block_Interface`. The interface contains 3 methods. If your block extends `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` or `Mage_Core_Block_Template` you should be ok. Those blocks already contain the methods.
This block can do anything you want (including calling your helper method). It acts as all the other blocks in Magento.
Then you will need to create a `widget.xml` file in the `etc` folder of your extension where you define the widget.
You specify in this file the widget code as a tag (it has to be unique over all Magento otherwise you just override an existing widget). On this tag define an attribute `type` with the block alias, then in a subtag add the name and the description of your widget and any parameters it may have.
When you are done, clear the cache and your widget should appear in the widgets dropdown when you try to add a widget to a page.